# Storing unconfirmed and confirmed data to a database

Tags: mysql, persistence, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am creating a web application using Strongloop using a MySQL database connector.

I want it to be possible, that a user can modify data in the application - but that this data will not be 'saved' until a user expressly chooses to save the data.

On the other hand, this is a web application and I don't want to keep the data in the user's session or local storage - I want this data to be immediately persisted so it can be recovered easily if the user loses their session.

To implement it I am thinking of doing the following, but I'm not sure if this is a good idea, or if there is a better way to be doing this.

This is one was I can implement it without doing too much customization on an existing relation:

1. add an new generated index as the primary key for the table
2. add a new generated index that represents the item in the row
   this would be generated for new items, or set to an old item for edits
3. add a boolean attribute 'saved'

Data will be written as 'saved=false'. To 'save' the data, the row is marked saved and the old row is deleted. The old row can be looked up by it's key, the second attribute in the row.

The way I was thinking of implementing it is to create a base entity called Saveable. Then every Database entity that extends Saveable will also have the 'Saveable' property.

Saveable has:

1. A generated id number
2. A generated non id number - the key for the real object
3. A 'saved' attribute

I would then put a method in Savable.js to perform the save operation and expose it via the API, and a method to intercept new writes and store them as unsaved.

My question is - is this a reasonable way to achieve what I want?